# Calculate normals for plane inside fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a situation where I need to do light shading. I don't have a vertex shader so I can't interpolate normals into my fragment shader.  Also I have no ability to pass in a normal map.  Can I generate normals completely in the fragment shader based,for example on fragment coordinates?  The geometry is always planar in my case.

And to extend on what I am trying to do:

I am using the [`NV_path_rendering`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/gamedev/files/GL_NV_path_rendering.txt) extension which allows [rendering pure vector graphics on GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/nv-path-rendering).  The problem is that only the fragment stage is accessible via shader which basically means - I can't use a vertex shader with NV_Path objects.

Comment: "I don't have a vertex shader" Huh? How that, are you using OpenGL-2? Normally you must supply at least a VS and a FS to make things work. Just a FS only works with having the VS being fixed function.

Comment: No, I am using NV_PATH text which allows shader access only via fragment stage.

Comment: Can you just write the vertex shader then?

Comment: No,the NV_PATH clearly states that only a fragment shader can be  used with it as it uses a completely different pipeline for primitive transforms...

Comment: In fact I was told by NVidia dudes that I can/should calculate my normals inside the fragment shader if I need to shade the path.

Comment: @MichaelIV: I suggest you put that information into your original question.

Comment: Updated.So any clues guys?may be via gl_FragCoords?

Comment: But if that extension uses a totally different pipeline for 2D vector graphics, is there even a proper notion 3-space from which to calculate a normal at all? Some more insights on what you are actually rendering and trying to compute would be interesting.

Comment: The NV_PATH SDK has actually a demo called "shader" where a text is shaded with phong light.but they pass a normal map into the fragment shader.The guy from NVidia NV_PATH team told me it is rather a clumsy way of getting normals for ligths and that I should calculate them inside the fragment.

Comment: @MichaelIV But then you need some way to calculate them on your own, since you're just rendering a plain 2D text. You don't have any spatial information to extract normals from. That's why I was asking for a more specific request of what you want to achieve and what you already do. Or more thorough description of the effect (with an image maybe?), since text shaded with Phong light doesn't really tell much, there's a million ways that could look like(based on, well, how the normals are computed).

Comment: The pipeline,although separate, does use some of fixed functionality.For example I do have access to uvs (as in old pipeline) inside the fragment shader.NVidia docs aren't descriptive either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your shapes are flat and NV_PATH require compat profile you can pass normal through on of built-in varyings gl_Color or gl_SecondaryColor

Extension description says that there is some kind of interpolation:

> Interpolation of per-vertex data (section 3.6.1). Path primitives have neither conventional vertices nor per-vertex data.  Instead fragments generate interpolated per-fragment colors, texture coordinate sets, and fog coordinates as a linear function of object-space or eye-space path coordinate's or using the current color, texture coordinate set, or fog coordinate state directly.

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/gamedev/files/GL_NV_path_rendering.txt

Comment: But on the second thought I am not sure it will work as the color won't interpolate.There are no vertices...

Comment: @MichaelIV what do you want to achieve? From what you have written I understood that yours geometry is flat means that you would have one normal per curve, it seems that is not true.

Comment: That is the point,there is no "geometry".It is paths.They are rasterized differently than the vertex based geometry.If you read about NV_PATH you will get what I mean.

Comment: @MichaelIV then what do you mean by "The geometry is always planar in my case"?

Comment: Yes you are right,my bad...The "geometry" is vector shape(can be text or any other shape)but it's flat as plane geometry.

Comment: Also added citation from NV_PATH description

Comment: @MichaelIV but what do you mean by planar? My impression was that it means that normal is the same for the whole shape, but looks like it is not what you want.

Comment: Yes it is on normal's z.But normal x and y should vary.Because in NV_PATH pipeline there is no vertex interpolation I can't use your proposed solution.I need somehow calculate the normals based on what I have in fragment shader

Comment: @MichaelIV but you have interpolation, just not from vertex data, and in docs I see description on how to control what is interpolated.

Comment: Maybe I missed it..What is the doc name?

Comment: @MichaelIV http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/gamedev/files/GL_NV_path_rendering.txt

search by word interpolation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33096/discussion-between-michael-iv-and-vasaka)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method which "sets the normal as the face normal", without knowing anything about vertex normals (as I understand it).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532576/738675

I have a three.js demo working here:

http://meetar.github.io/three.js-normal-map-0/index6.html

My implementation is getting vertex position data from the vertex shader, but it sounds like you're able to get that through other means.